# Handling Multiple Gestures on a View

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiwebview, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

Is there any way to detect a single tap vs. a scrolling gesture on a UIWebView?

I have a UIWebView, that contains rich text that many times, scrolls, if there is a lot of text content. I need to add a new feature that will allow the user to tap the UIWebView to get different content.

The problem is, my solution for this was to place a clear custom button on top of the UIWebView, which handles the tap but kills the scrolling feature. How do the cool kids do this type of thing?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a gesture recognizer. This eliminates the need for the UIButton overlay altogether.

```
    //Handle taps on the UIWebView
    self.singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(**tapDetected:**)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    singleTap.delegate = self;
    [self.readAboutItView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

   //Set up the event handler
- (IBAction)**tapDetected:**(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {

   //Do something with the content
   [self webViewTouched:self];

}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{


    return YES;

}

-(BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{


    return YES;


}
```